# Weird NSMutableDictionary behavior

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsmutabledictionary

I have an iPhone app with 4 tab bar items. One of them is a map. I get the user's current location and calculate the distance from the user to some locations around the city. I store the coordinates for those locations and the distances in a NSMutableDictionary.

```
distanceDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:coordinates forKeys:distance];
```

On my navigatonbar I have a button that says "list", so you can see the nearest locations from your current position. I do the calculation while the user is waiting to see the result in a tableview. This work great, I can you push the button as many times as you like, and get the right result. However, if you press another tab bar item, i.e "News", go back to the map and press the list button, the dictionary is empty.

I put an NSLog with the number of keys in the dictionary in

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

This method gets called both when you click the List button on the navigation bar and when you to another tab. When you click the List button, it shows the correct number of keys, but when you go to another tab it says 0.

I have not released the dictionary, nor it's objects or keys. I can't figure out what's causing this. Any idea?

Comment: Where are you initializing the dictionary?  In `init`?  In `loadView`?  If you assign `distanceDic = ...` in loadView and loadView happens twice, then it would make sense that all the data would be lost.

Comment: Right, where is the dictionary getting created & initialized?  (And remember that `count` will report zero on a nil pointer, so make sure the dictionary even exists when it's reporting zero.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a breakpoint in your dealloc method where this dictionary gets released.  In fact, put a breakpoint wherever this dictionary gets released. Just search for distanceDic and releases or "self.distanceDic = nil" or [self setDistanceDic:nil] statements. Then run your program and watch what breakpoint gets hit. You'll have your answer then. I'm suspecting that you've defined it as a @property(nonatomic, retain) and that it either gets thrown away when you hit the tab bar and go to a new controller, or it loads in a new one, and you're looking at a released one.

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that the view is being unloaded due to a low memory warning, and then reloaded the next time you go to its tab. `-viewDidLoad` will be called again, and depending on your implementation this could cause you to lose all your view's state.

Comment: I'm not using -viewDidLoad. I'm using loadView and viewDidAppear. But can it be that viewDidUnload method might be setting my dictionary to nil? Can I use the copy property to avoid this?

Comment: Well -loadView will also be called twice if the view is reloaded. But this is just one of many possibilities.

Comment: loadView gets called when the user returns to the map, after clicking the List button. Not when user goes to another tab, then back.